# Counting trending tweets with geo code

Tags: twitter, tweetsharp

I am trying to find trending tweets  by each city in Turkey. but "TwitterGeoLocationSearch" result return zero . I am using TweetSharp 2.0 and visual studio 2010.

Please check my code block. Here:

```
      private void btnTweetSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    service = new TwitterService("xxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx");

     var   CityGeoCode = new TwitterGeoLocationSearch(37.0000000, 35.3213330, 10, TwitterGeoLocationSearch.RadiusType.Km);

    var tweetss = service.Search(new SearchOptions { Q = " Turkey ", Count = 1000, Geocode = CityGeoCode });

            var TweetwithGeo = tweetss.Statuses.Where(x => x.Location != null );

          foreach (var tweet in TweetwithGeo)
            {

                    lbTweetWindow.Items.Add(tweet.Text);

                }

        }
```

}

Any help, would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly executing.
Just go to twitter developers and get your consumerKey, consumerSecret, AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret

```
    private void btnTweetSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

            /* Your Authentication Code */
            var service = new TwitterService(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret);
            service.AuthenticateWith(_accessToken, _accessTokenSecret);

            /* Your Tweet Extracting code */
            var   CityGeoCode = new TwitterGeoLocationSearch(37.0000000, 35.3213330, 10, TwitterGeoLocationSearch.RadiusType.Km);

            var tweetss = service.Search(new SearchOptions { Q = " Turkey ", Count = 1000, Geocode = CityGeoCode });

            var TweetwithGeo = tweetss.Statuses.Where(x => x.Location != null );

            foreach (var tweet in TweetwithGeo)
            {

                lbTweetWindow.Items.Add(tweet.Text);
            }

     }
```